# Reopening the file of a memory mapped region

Tags: linux, windows, process, posix

Is there a way in various POSIX-like OSes to determine which file was mapped to a memory region using `mmap`? Linux has `/proc/self/maps` which contains not only the file name but also the device and inode numbers. That can be used to be sure if the reopened file is the same as the mapped one, even if the original file had been unlinked and replaced. Is there a similar mechanism for BSD or OS X?

Is there a way to do this in Windows, having the address of a region? Windows does not have the problem of a file being replaced during use, given its file locking semantics.